# How can I align at center "div" and "a" elements

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I making "header" component in Vue. I needs to align all links and an images at center. But when I try, first or second div element going up or down. And I have logo and text in one div.

Here's my code

HTML

```
<template>
 <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header__left">
        <div class="left__logo">
        <img class="logo" src="../assets/popcorn.svg" />
        <div class="logo__content">Vue BestMovies</div>
        </div>
        <div class="header__links">
        <router-link to="/">Movies</router-link>
        <router-link to="/tv">TV Show</router-link>
        <router-link to="/actors">Actors</router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="" id="" />
  </div>
    </div>
 </header>
</template>
```

CSS

```
    <style lang="scss" scoped>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap");
.header {
padding-top: 30px;
}
.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.header__left {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.left__logo {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}
.logo {
height: 42px;
}
.logo__content {
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: "Crimson Text", serif;
padding-left: 13px;
}
.header__links {
padding-left: 60px;
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
}
</style>
```

This is the result:

[image]

So, what I can alight item?

Comment: set height of the logo accordingly and use align-items:center on container class

Comment: This is doesn't work. Vue BestMovies is still taller prnt.sc/zra74d

Comment: have you tried to remove the height of the logo. .logo {
  height: auto;
}  .container{ display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
}

Comment: It's doesn't work - https://prnt.sc/zrdggx

Answer (score 1):

use `align-items: center` on `.container` class

I made a working example of center alignment.
[example here](https://codepen.io/undefinednishant/pen/rNWmOGo)

Comment: This is doesn't work. Vue BestMovies is still taller
https://prnt.sc/zra74d